# set tinymce in " javascript, $(document).ready...", my solution is not working

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i use javascript made a function that every time i click button "add one more" button, html page will add another group of html elements, which i need to includes tinymce text area, but I cannot manage to do it.

here is part of my code,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e) {
var html = '<textarea class="tinymce" name="CCV_product_full_description[]" id="childccv-product-full-description" />'; 
...
```

I defined tinymce in another js file and included in this html file, but it not works some how, i need some help :)

in another js file

```
tinymce.init({
selector:"textarea.tinymce"
});
```

here is the function for add another group of html elements

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {
        $("#container").append(html);

    });
```

Comment: `class="tinymcee"` !== `"textarea.tinymce"`

Comment: `class="tinymcee"` in html and `selector:"textarea.tinymce"` in another js file. check for `e` s once

Comment: I solve the typo problem, but still not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to initialize the editor on DOM elements that don't yet exist.

Also, if you are trying to dynamically add several instances of TinyMCE, you need to remove TinyMCE first before you can call it again.

```
$("#add").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#container").append(html);
    tinymce.remove()
    tinymce.init({
    selector:".yourSelectorName"
    });
  });
```